# How to track changes in currently visible ViewController as user navigating the screens in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, firebase-analytics

I'm trying to replicate Firebase Analytics behaviour, which automatically fire screen events whenever ViewController screen get's changed with another.
Though I'm able to find currently visible ViewController using :

> UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController

But I need some way to get notified for any change in rootViewController. I tried to observe this **rootViewController** using KVO, but I don't get any callback. I found that KVO only works on NSObject with dynamic properties.
Is there any way I could receive callback for change in ViewController?  Since this will be a library project, I couldn't make changes in main code to support the feature.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you been able to find solution?

Comment: Yes, using Method Swizzling, we can create our own implementation of viewDidAppear/load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following solution worked for me:-

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

public extension UIViewController {

@objc dynamic func _tracked_viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    UserActivityTracker.startTracking(viewController: self)
}

static func swizzle() {
        //Make sure This isn't a subclass of UIViewController,
        //So that It applies to all UIViewController childs
        if self != UIViewController.self {
            return
        }
        let _: () = {
            let originalSelector =
                #selector(UIViewController.viewWillAppear(_:))
            let swizzledSelector =
                #selector(UIViewController._tracked_viewWillAppear(_:))
            let originalMethod =
                class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector)
            let swizzledMethod =
                class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector)
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod!, swizzledMethod!);
        }()
    }
 }
```

In above code _tracked_viewWillAppear() is my custom function which I want to call my implementation before actual implementation called.
Then in AppDeligate class, call UIViewController.swizzle() method, as follows:-

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController.swizzle()
    return true
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do the same in SwiftUI?